Self-referential pointer to field inside of same ctypes structure doesn't output usable type
I'm trying to recreate this structure (from https://github.com/ac-custom-shaders-patch/acc-extension-config/wiki/Other-Things-%E2%80%93-Custom-AI#drawing-debug-lines)...
struct cai_debug_lines {
  int count;
  cai_debug_line lines[count];
}

struct cai_debug_line {
  float3 from;
  float3 to;
  uint color;
}

...in Python 3.12 using ctypes. However, I'm stuck on the definition of line 3:
  cai_debug_line lines[count];

I think I understand what it means: there are count number of cai_debug_line structs which are of name lines, with count being stored in the same struct one line above as an integer, which makes sense as there might be zero or more cai_debug_lines that you would want to display.
I've tried the following Python code...
import ctypes
from ctypes import c_int32, c_float, c_wchar, c_bool, c_uint32, POINTER, Array, c_int, c_uint, c_long, pointer

class CAIDebugLine(ctypes.Structure):
    _pack_ = 4
    _fields_ = [
        ('point_from', c_float * 3),
        ('point_to', c_float * 3),
        ('color', c_uint),
    ]


class CAIDebugLines(ctypes.Structure):
    _pack_ = 4
    _fields_ = [
        ('count', c_int),
        ('lines', CAIDebugLine * CAIDebugLines.count),
    ]

...which throws:
    ('lines', CAIDebugLine * CAIDebugLines.count),
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
NameError: name 'CAIDebugLines' is not defined. Did you mean: 'CAIDebugLine'?

which makes sense, as CAIDebugLines isn't defined yet. I attempted to circumvent that through:
class CAIDebugLine(ctypes.Structure):
    _pack_ = 4
    _fields_ = [
        ('point_from', c_float * 3),
        ('point_to', c_float * 3),
        ('color', c_uint),
    ]


class CAIDebugLines(ctypes.Structure):
    _pack_ = 4
    _fields_ = [
        ('count', c_int)
    ]


CAIDebugLines._fields_ = [
    ('lines', CAIDebugLine * CAIDebugLines.count)
]

which threw:
    ('lines', CAIDebugLine * CAIDebugLines.count)
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type '_ctypes.CField'

I thought the above might work based on the ctypes documentation here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#incomplete-types , but that seems to be only talking about a struct referencing itself, as in its whole self, not a part of itself. It also shows that it uses POINTER(), so I tried enclosing various sections of the second-to-last line above with that, as well as its lowercase version, but that threw more errors:
    ('lines', pointer(CAIDebugLine) * CAIDebugLines.count)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: _type_ must have storage info

    ('lines', POINTER(CAIDebugLine) * CAIDebugLines.count)
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type '_ctypes.CField'

    ('lines', CAIDebugLine * pointer(CAIDebugLines.count))
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: _type_ must have storage info

    ('lines', CAIDebugLine * POINTER(CAIDebugLines.count))
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: must be a ctypes type

I haven't found anything that works for this yet and I'm out of ideas.

I don't think that's actually a valid C or C++ struct definition. Looking at the page you linked, it looks like they're just using a vaguely C-inspired syntax.

@user2357112 So it just won't work? I guess I should have familiarized myself with C++ structs a bit further before scouring the ctypes docs for any reference of this supposedly nonexistent C++ feature...

Your understanding sounds right to me. @user2357112 is correct that it isn't valid C or C++. C incomplete types don't help. They are primarily about avoiding a valid complete definition where that detail isn't required. In C++, you would probably use a std::vector<cai_debug_line>, though it would have a different memory layout. In C, you could come closer by using a Flexible Array Member (FAM). Instances of FAM's must each be individually dynamically allocated.

That's not valid in C or Python. Might be a duplicate of  [SO]: Setting _fields_ dynamically in ctypes.Structure (@CristiFati's answer).
